# typescript error on assignment of subscribe event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Here is my ts code : after `this.store.pipe` I am assigning the data to `courseList` - but getting typscript error as :

> **ERROR in
>   src/app/setup-config/setup-config/setup-config.component.ts(55,4):
>   error TS2740: Type 'ModelCourse[]' is missing the following properties
>   from type 'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator,
>   lift, and 5 more**.

what is that mean? what is the correction do i require to do here?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StateSetupConfig, ModelCourse } from "./../models";
import { LoadCourse } from "./../state/course.actions";
import * as setupConfigActions from "./../state/setup-config.actions";
import * as actions from "./../state";

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;

@Component({
    selector: 'setup-config',
    templateUrl: './setup-config.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./setup-config.component.scss']
})
export class SetupConfigComponent implements OnInit {


    courseList:Observable<ModelCourse[]>


    constructor(private store:Store<StateSetupConfig>) { }

    ngOnInit(){ 


        this.store.dispatch(new LoadCourse());

        this.store.pipe(select(actions.getCourses)).subscribe((data:ModelCourse[]) => {
            this.courseList = data;
        })

    }


}
```

[image: typescript error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to assign the actual value of type `ModelCourse[]` to your class member of type `Observable<ModelCourse[]`.

The cleanest way would be to assign your store selector directly like:

```
public readonly courseList$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(actions.getCourses),
);
```

And inside your template use the `async`-pipe to retrieve the value like:

```
<div *ngFor="let course of courseList$ | async">
  <!-- example -->
</div>
```

This way you don't have to take care of unsubscribing on component destruction.

A little site note:
If you use the data in multiple places and always want the latest value you can add the `shareReplay` operator to your stream after the `select` operator.

Comment: But I require the subscription here, because I need to add a additional property to array object using map...

Comment: No need for a subscription, just use rxjs operators (for example the `map` operator) to apply modification.

Comment: so this is correct : `public readonly courseList$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(actions.getCourses).map(data => ...),); ` - getting error as `map dosen't existing on Observable<ModelCourse[]>`

Comment: No you have to use the rxjs operator like: `store.pipe(select(...), map(...))`